# showing sum of values written in query to textfield in java

Tags: java, sum

In order to get the sum of result in to the textfield,i had written the code like this but the value is not getting on the field.

```
private void fillTotalAmount(String valueToSearch) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Connection connection=null;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/restaurant","root","");
        String Query = "select sum(amount) as amount from invoice where invoice_no=?";
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(Query);
        ps.setString(1,"%"+valueToSearch+"%");
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        System.out.println(rs);
        while(rs.next())
        {
          txt_Total_Amount.setText(String.valueOf(Query));
        }

    }
    catch(SQLException e1)
    {
        //Logger.getLogger(additem.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e1);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"No Records Found");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

please help me to solve my problem,thanks in advance

Comment: Why `,"%"+valueToSearch+"%"` with `=`? Do you want to use `like`?

Comment: Also i think you miss the `Group by` clause

Comment: This will set the textfield to ```"select sum(amount) as amount from invoice where invoice_no=?"``` because thats what the ```Query``` variable contains. You probably want to set it to ```rs.getInt(1)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `rs.getInt(1)` to get the first column of the resultset

```
txt_Total_Amount.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getInt(1)));
```